# conditional `orderBy` or `DB::Raw` inside `orderBy` in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sql-order-by

I am trying to show appointment list in `asc` order for specific next days from today.(Ex:next 5 days or 10 days). Only from today, the next 5 days or 10 days(**note**: days will be dynamic, I mean client will setup).When `today` date will over then this date should not come into the days I mentioned(from today to next 5 days). I am trying with `orderBy` method something like bellow -

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$appointments = Appointment::with('Customer')
         ->orderBy(DB::raw("('appointment_time', '>=', ${today})"), 'asc')->get();

return view("ManageAppointment", compact(['appointments']));
```

For sure, I am getting the bellow error -

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) (SQL: select * from `appointments` order by ('appointment_time', '>=', 2019-07-27) asc)

What should I do to get the expected result, would someone help me please?

Comment: What is the columns u need to order by??

Comment: try this: `DB::raw("(appointment_time >= '${today}')")`

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$tomorrow = Carbon::tomorrow(); //2019-07-28 00:00:00
$nextdate = Carbon::now()->addDays(5); //dynamic day(5days, 10days) //2019-08-01 00:00:00

$appointments = Appointment::with('Customer')
                      ->whereBetween('appointment_time', [$tomorrow,$nextdate])
                      ->orderBy('appointment_time','asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so with `WHERE` clause not with `ORDER BY` do some thing like this:

```
<?php 

    $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $next5Days = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+5 days'));
    $appointments = Appointment::with('Customer')
           ->where('appointment_time','>=',$current_date)
           ->where('appointment_time','<=',$next5Days)
     ->orderBy('appointment_time', 'asc')->get(); 
?>
```

This will generate something like this.

```
SELECT * from appointments_table where appointment_time <= 2019-07-27 18:30:58 
AND where appointment_time <= 2019-08-31 00:00:00 ORDER BY appointment_time ASC
```

Hope it works for you! :)